# Progress dialog bar loading error in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I tried to add custom progress dialog bar to my app.

it display the two progress bars at a time. 
Like below

[image]

This is the style.xml code

```
    <style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#daac56</item>
    <item name="android:background">#160203</item>
</style>
```

This is the activity code.

```
myPd_bar=new ProgressDialog(Restaurant_List.this,R.style.Theme_MyDialog);
            myPd_bar.setMessage("Loading....");
            myPd_bar.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            myPd_bar.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
```

I want to change font family,the text color and the progress dialog background color. this just only change the content text color. not title color.

**Edited**

I want like this bar

[image]

this title and text color should be change.
can anyone tell me the error i did?

Comment: what you mean by stacktrace?

Comment: Please post error logs.

Comment: Read http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/280

Comment: stacktrace i.e. logcat details which shows the proper & full description when & where you are getting exception or error.

Comment: @i.n.e.f she is not getting any error. Then why the logs....?

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar Her Question Title "Progress dialog bar loading "ERROR" in android" looks like she is getting ERROR. i.e the Reason i am asking for error Logs.

Comment: here it display the two windows.on top of other. i want to remove one and change the title color.

Comment: Hey did you set theme of Activity?

Comment: yes. this is the code android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > @Pankaj Kumar

Answer (score 0):

create custom style and add sufficient attribute according to your requirement like

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#daa212</item>
    <item name="android:background">#001541</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i added this and, then it looks like my new image. i want to remove its under frame and title bar text color and font color.

Comment: i mean use Dialog class instead ofProgressDialog

Comment: No i want progress dialog bar. @santhosh